# Screen freezing after a while (22.04 and 20.04)

Tags: nvidia, freeze, crash, 22.04

While running Ubuntu 20.04, my system will completely freeze, my keyboard and audio disconnect, and any input does nothing. I have to hold the power button to restart the machine.

Additionally, I have had a similar problem where the system cuts out for a moment and then the fans come back on but no video appears on my monitor and I similarly have to hold the power button.

I tried a few things. From what I remember, I have:
Increased my swap size,
Updated my GPU Drivers,
and eventually, I upgraded to 22.04 with high hopes, but the problem persists.

The usual scenario is that I am running simulations in R which use the GPU and CPU when the system crashes, but it has happened between runs as well when I am doing nothing demanding.

My specs are:

- RTX 3080 Ti
- i7-12700K,
- 32GB DDR4,
- 1TB Samsung M.2 SSD,
- Aorus Z690

Now running Ubuntu 22.04, but the problem started on 20.04

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. My computer simply freezes from time to time whether it's on load or not. I also have an NVIDIA card, but mine is the 3070.

Comment: Best of luck solving your issue, mine turned out to be nothing to do with Ubuntu or any programs, I had a faulty CPU. So, perhaps try a repair shop.

Comment: Found out my problem was RAM and not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced frequent freezing after upgrading ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 until I changed from wayland to Xorg, after which there were no problems.